# Can ruamel.yaml force a blank newline between blocks when dumping?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have a large number of yaml files where I need to rename some of the keys in every file and maintain the existing order of all the data. I have written the following code to enable that but after dumping the yaml files back, where once there were blank lines between blocks, these have often disappeared.

The documentation for ruamel.yaml isn't entirely clear to me so I'm hoping someone here can help to enhance my code by adding that functionality. Maybe there is a setting that I'm not aware of that can enforce a newline between blocks?

I'm using python 3.10 and the latest version of ruamel.yaml

Here is my code:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

class YAMLKeyRenamer:
    @staticmethod
    def rename_key(data: dict[str, Any] | list[dict[str, Any]], keys: list[str], new_key: str) -> dict[str, Any] | list[dict[str, Any]]:
        """
        Recursively renames the last key, as referenced by a list of keys, in a nested dictionary or list of dictionaries whilst maintaining the order of all the keys.

        Args:
            data (dict[str, Any] | list[dict[str, Any]]): The input data (dictionary or list of dictionaries).
            keys (list[str]): The list of keys representing the hierarchy to the key to be renamed.
            new_key (str): The new name for the last key in the hierarchy.

        Returns:
            dict[str, Any] | list[dict[str, Any]]: The updated data with the last key renamed.

        Examples:
            >>> test_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 1, 'd': 3}, 'e': [{'f': 4}, {'f': 5}, {'a': 1}]}
            >>> renamed_dict = rename_key(test_dict, ['a'], 'new_key')
            >>> print(renamed_dict)
            {'new_key': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 1, 'd': 3}, 'e': [{'f': 4}, {'f': 5}, {'a': 1}]}

            >>> renamed_dict = rename_key(test_dict, ['c', 'd'], 'new_key')
            >>> print(renamed_dict)
            {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 1, 'new_key': 3}, 'e': [{'f': 4}, {'f': 5}, {'a': 1}]}

            >>> renamed_dict = rename_key(test_dict, ['e', 'f'], 'new_key')
            >>> print(renamed_dict)
            {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': {'a': 1, 'd': 3}, 'e': [{'new_key': 4}, {'new_key': 5}, {'a': 1}]}
        """
        if len(keys) == 1:
            if isinstance(data, dict):
                return {new_key if key == keys[0] else key: value for key, value in data.items()}
            elif isinstance(data, list):
                return [YAMLKeyRenamer.rename_key(item, keys, new_key) for item in data]

        if isinstance(data, dict):
            new_data = {}
            for key, value in data.items():
                new_data[key] = YAMLKeyRenamer.rename_key(value, keys[1:], new_key) if key == keys[0] else value
            return new_data
        elif isinstance(data, list):
            return [YAMLKeyRenamer.rename_key(item, keys, new_key) for item in data]
        else:
            return data


    @staticmethod
    def update_yaml_file(input_file: str, output_file: str, keys_to_update: list[str], new_key: str) -> None:
        """
        Renames the keys in a YAML file whilst preserving order and structure of those keys.

        Args:
            input_file: The path to the input YAML file.
            output_file: The path to save the updated YAML file.
            keys_to_update: The list of keys representing the path to the key to be renamed.
            new_key: The new name for the key.
        """
        yaml = YAML()
        yaml.preserve_quotes = True    

        # Load YAML file
        with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
            yaml_data = yaml.load(file)

        # Rename keys
        renamed_data = YAMLKeyRenamer.rename_key(yaml_data, keys_to_update, new_key)

        # Save updated data to YAML file
        with open(output_file, 'w') as file:
            yaml.dump(renamed_data, file)
```

The yaml files are checked against a json schema that I'm not at liberty to post here and where many blocks and keys are optional, so I'm looking for a generic solution if possible. I also appreciate the rename_key() method isn't the most efficient as it rebuilds the dictionary key-by-key - that's a problem for another day.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to provide a minimal example that shows your issue. In this case that would include an example YAML file. The easier you make it to reproduce an error/problem, the more likely an appropriate answer (that solves the issue) will be given. In the process of reducing the problem to its core, you might even find a solution yourself. Thanks are not necessary on SO, and waste bandwith of future readers of the question. Upvote (once you can), accept answers and/or comment if appropriate to show your appreciation.

Answer (score 1):

It is always good to include a full and minimal example on SO, and for processing YAML that includes a minimal YAML file
that shows the problem. You
provide some test_dict input, but that doesn't show the structure of the YAML that you are using.

From the context
I assume that you have some block structured YAML.
If you use the default roundtrip loader/dumper on that blank lines are preserved ( I included end-of-line comments on
the lines precding the blank lines, to make
the way comments are preserved more clear in the explanation, these comments are not necessary).

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a: 1
b: 2                      # c1

c: {a: 1, d: 3}           # c2

d:
  x: 1
  y: 3                    # c3

e: [f: 4, f: 5, a: 1]     # c4

"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: 1
b: 2                      # c1

c: {a: 1, d: 3}           # c2

d:
  x: 1
  y: 3                    # c3

e: [f: 4, f: 5, a: 1]     # c4
```

What you have to be aware of is that:

- `data` is not a dict, it is a `ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap()` instance that behaves like a dict
- the blank lines are stored as extensions of (empty) end-of-line comments attached to the `.ca` attribute of the `CommentedMap`
- comments are normally attached to the preceding node (in `ruamel.yaml<=0.17)

You can inspect this by e.g. doing:

```py
print('type:', type(data))
print('comment attribute:', data.ca)
```

printing:

```
type: <class 'ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap'>
comment attribute: Comment(comment=None,
  items={'b': [None, None, CommentToken('# c1\n\n', line: 1, col: 26), None], 'c': [None, None, CommentToken('# c2\n\n', line: 3, col: 26), None], 'e': [None, None, CommentToken('# c4\n\n', line: 9, col: 26), None]})
```

Your `YAMLKeyRenamer` returns a normal dict which throws away the `.ca` attribute on the root level, and thus throws away
the emtpy lines.

If you look at the `items`, you'll see that there is no key `d` (and no comment `# c3`), that is because the newline after
`# c3` is actually stored on `data['d'].ca` and that probably explains why some, but not all empty lines disappear, as you
only change root level keys and you do not (recursively) update keys.

If you are going to change a key and want to both keep the empty-line and keep the order it is probably easiest to
use index, pop and insert to update the `CommentedMap`:

```py
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a: 1
b: 2

c: {a: 1, d: 3}

d:
  x: 1
  y: 3

e: [f: 4, f: 5, a: 1]

"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True

def change_key(d, frm, to):
    assert isinstance(d, ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap)
    try:
        pos = list(d.keys()).index(frm)
    except ValueError:  # frm is not a key of d
        return
    d.insert(pos, to, d.pop(frm))


data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
change_key(data, 'c', 'hello')
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
a: 1
b: 2

hello: {a: 1, d: 3}

d:
  x: 1
  y: 3

e: [f: 4, f: 5, a: 1]
```

And if you want to replace keys on every level you can walk over `data` recursivly on keys, values and elements (as keys can be mappings or sequences as well, although you probably don't have any)

```
def recursive_update(d, fun):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        fun(d)
        for k, v in d.items():
            recursive_update(k, fun)
            recursive_update(v, fun)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for elem in d:
            recursive_update(elem)
```

That way you also catch keys in mappings nested under a sequence.

I would also make a class `KeyUpdater` that stores the list of key-mappings on initialisation, and then implement `__call__` on that class so you can pass an instance as second parameter to `update_recursive`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @Anthon, I like the simplicity of your answer. One thing though, this will only change a top-level key - do you have any thoughts on how to make it change a key at a specific level? I guess I could look at implementing the same recursive methodology as I used earlier?

Comment: Yes you could, although I tend to prefer a generic "walker" of data loaded from YAML and then pass in the function that does the work, or a class instance (that can store parameters during `__init__` and has the `__call__` method). See the updated answer.